# Deploying CGI on Pythonanywhere

Tags: python, deployment, cgi, pythonanywhere

I want to use Pythonanywhere for deploying my CGI-projects. I've uploaded home/[username]/hello.py file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

print "Content-type: text/html\n"
print "<h1>Hello world!</h1>"
```

I think I should edit /var/www/[username]_pythonanywhere_wsgi.py and/or launch something like

```
python2 -m CGIHTTPServer
```

from /home/[username], but I can't understand what me to do. I want to run code described above by loading [username].pythonanywhere.com/hello.py. Also I have some html-s, css-s and other static files, and I want them to be opened too. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

PythonAnywhere dev here, we don't support the CGI model of web applications.  We use a python protocol called "wsgi" instead.  You can hand-write your own wsgi-compatible services, but most people choose to use a web framework like django or flask instead.

Head over to the "web" tab for some more info and some examples.